# how do i Remove ALL scripts from wordpress using wp_dequeue_script or wp_deregister_scripts

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Im trying to remove all script from a certain page temp so i added this above the doctype

```
<?php 

 wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery' );
 wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

 ?>
```

but its not working. any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add this code to your functions.php

```
function dequeue_script() {
    if ( is_page_template('page-pop.php') ) {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'dequeue_script', 100 );
```

The `if ( is_page_template('page-pop.php') ) {}` statement is used here to define the page template to which a function will be coupled. You just need to change the template name (page-pop.php) to the template you want to use it on

Answer (score 2):

This script will remove ALL scripts from your page, not just jquery

```
public function dequeue_all_scripts(){
    // Replace the conditional check below with your own...
    if (is_singular('myposttype')){
        global $wp_scripts;
        $scripts = $wp_scripts->registered;
        foreach ( $scripts as $script ){
            wp_dequeue_script($script->handle);
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'dequeue_all_scripts');
```